# How to unificare function (connect 3 functions into 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Would like to merge 3 functions into 1, because I feel like it is possible, but I have no idea how to make it correctly

Here is my solutuion. I do not understand why it only hides location-type2 and does not show it.

I have really no idea what is wrong here, because it hides things correctly, it just does not show them at all.

Also, here is my HTML. I am catching value from "data-value" and using this I am trying to merge this functions, but it does not work.

```js
$("#check3, #check2, #check1").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).data("value"));
    if ($(this).data("value") === 1) {

        if ($("#check1").checked) {
            $(".location-type1").removeClass("display-none");
        }
        else {
            $(".location-type1").addClass("display-none");
        }

    }
    else if ($(this).data("value") === 2) {
        if ($("#check2").checked) {
            $(".location-type2").removeClass("display-none");
        }
        else {
            $(".location-type2").addClass("display-none");
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($("#check3").checked) {
            $(".location-type3").removeClass("display-none");
        }
        else {
            $(".location-type3").addClass("display-none");
        }
    }

});
```

I would like to have this 3 functiones being merged:

```
$("#check1").click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('check1').checked)
        { 
            $(".location-type1").removeClass("display-none")
        }
    else {
         $(".location-type1").addClass("display-none");
    }
});
$("#check2").click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('check2').checked)
        {
            $(".location-type2").removeClass("display-none")
        }
    else {

        $(".location-type2").addClass("display-none");
    }
$("#check3").click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('check3').checked)
        {
            $(".location-type3").removeClass("display-none")
        }
    else {

        $(".location-type3").addClass("display-none");
    }
});      

     <div class="form-group">  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="check1" data-value="1" checked> <label for="check1">Restauracja</label> </div>
     <div class="shop-position location-type1" data-lat="52.4068200" data-lng="16.9299300" data-type="1">
            <div class="location-text">
        <strong>Vininova1</strong>
            <div>Podgórna 14</div>
            <div>Poznań</div>
            <a href="#" class="show-on-map">Pokaż na mapie</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show the related HTML so we can have a working example. And then, we can show you how to accomplish this with just a single function.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've edited code and added some of my HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you find yourself writing the same or very similar code that you've already written, you should stop and think about how to re-write it to be more loosely coupled and therefore more usable. In your case, we really only need one function with a single statement in it.

Also, `input` elements already have a `value` attribute, so it's redundant to add a `data-value` to them.

Additionally, don't use inline styles if you can avoid it. They cause duplication of code and make the code more difficult to read and scale. Instead, use CSS classes.

```js
// Get the checkboxes into a JQuery wrapped set
let inputs = $("#parent input[type='checkbox']");

// Set the event handler up on the parent of the 3 checkboxes
$("#parent").on("click", function (event) {
  if(event.target.nodeName === "INPUT"){
    // Get the actual checkbox that was clicked with: event.target 
    // Get the index of the clicked checkbox within the set
    // Toggle the use of the class on the location item that corresponds to the index of the clicked checkbox(es)
    $("#locations div")[$("#parent input[type='checkbox']").index(event.target)].classList.toggle("display-none");
  }
});
```

```css
.display-none {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">One<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">Two<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="three">Three
</div>
<div id="locations">
  <div class=".location-type1 display-none">Location 1</div>
  <div class=".location-type2 display-none">Location 2</div>
  <div class=".location-type3 display-none">Location 3</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: at first it seemed complicated to me, but now I get it. Thank you very much for your answer, it was really helpful!

Comment: @KacperRuściński Please consider up voting all helpful answers and marking this one as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: Sure, with pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Use switch.
If you were using only data("value"), switch would be by this value:

```
switch(data("value")) {
    case...
}
```

But in your case checks are different. Then:

```
switch(true) {
    case data("value") === 2:
    ....
    case document.getElementById('check3').checked:
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was so simple. I feel like I am so dumb

Comment: `switch(true) === me sad`